# DirectX/C++: Marching Cubes Indexing

Tags: c++, algorithm, indexing, directx, marching-cubes

I've implemented the Marching Cube algorithm in a DirectX environment (To test and have fun). Upon completion, I noticed that the resulting model looks heavily distorted, as if the indices were off.

[image]

I've attempted to extract the indices, but I think the vertices are ordered correctly already, using the lookup tables, examples at http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/ . The current build uses a 15^3 volume.

Marching cubes iterates over the array as normal:

```
for (float iX = 0; iX < CellFieldSize.x; iX++){
    for (float iY = 0; iY < CellFieldSize.y; iY++){
        for (float iZ = 0; iZ < CellFieldSize.z; iZ++){
            MarchCubes(XMFLOAT3(iX*StepSize, iY*StepSize, iZ*StepSize), StepSize);
        }
    }
}
```

The MarchCube function is called:

```
void MC::MarchCubes(){

...

int Corner, Vertex, VertexTest, Edge, Triangle, FlagIndex, EdgeFlags;
float Offset;
XMFLOAT3 Color;
float CubeValue[8];
XMFLOAT3 EdgeVertex[12];
XMFLOAT3 EdgeNorm[12];

//Local copy 
for (Vertex = 0; Vertex < 8; Vertex++) {
    CubeValue[Vertex] = (this->*fSample)(
        in_Position.x + VertexOffset[Vertex][0] * Scale,
        in_Position.y + VertexOffset[Vertex][1] * Scale,
        in_Position.z + VertexOffset[Vertex][2] * Scale
  );  
}

FlagIndex = 0;
```

Intersection calculations:

```
...
//Test vertices for intersection.
for (VertexTest = 0; VertexTest < 8; VertexTest++){
    if (CubeValue[VertexTest] <= TargetValue) 
        FlagIndex |= 1 << VertexTest;
}

//Find which edges are intersected by the surface.
EdgeFlags = CubeEdgeFlags[FlagIndex];
if (EdgeFlags == 0){
    return;
}

for (Edge = 0; Edge < 12; Edge++){
    if (EdgeFlags & (1 << Edge)) {
        Offset = GetOffset(CubeValue[EdgeConnection[Edge][0]], CubeValue[EdgeConnection[Edge][1]], TargetValue); // Get offset function definition. Needed!
        EdgeVertex[Edge].x = in_Position.x + VertexOffset[EdgeConnection[Edge][0]][0] + Offset * EdgeDirection[Edge][0] * Scale;
        EdgeVertex[Edge].y = in_Position.y + VertexOffset[EdgeConnection[Edge][0]][1] + Offset * EdgeDirection[Edge][1] * Scale;
        EdgeVertex[Edge].z = in_Position.z + VertexOffset[EdgeConnection[Edge][0]][2] + Offset * EdgeDirection[Edge][2] * Scale;

        GetNormal(EdgeNorm[Edge], EdgeVertex[Edge].x, EdgeVertex[Edge].y, EdgeVertex[Edge].z); //Need normal values
    }
}
```

And the original implementation gets pushed into a holding struct for DirectX.

```
for (Triangle = 0; Triangle < 5; Triangle++) {

    if (TriangleConnectionTable[FlagIndex][3 * Triangle] < 0) break;

    for (Corner = 0; Corner < 3; Corner++) {
        Vertex = TriangleConnectionTable[FlagIndex][3 * Triangle + Corner];3 * Triangle + Corner]);
        GetColor(Color, EdgeVertex[Vertex], EdgeNorm[Vertex]);
        Data.VertexData.push_back(XMFLOAT3(EdgeVertex[Vertex].x, EdgeVertex[Vertex].y, EdgeVertex[Vertex].z));
        Data.NormalData.push_back(XMFLOAT3(EdgeNorm[Vertex].x, EdgeNorm[Vertex].y, EdgeNorm[Vertex].z));
        Data.ColorData.push_back(XMFLOAT4(Color.x, Color.y, Color.z, 1.0f));
    }
}
```

(This is the same ordering as the original GL implementation)

Comment: I suppose I'll take a fresh look this evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I missed a parenthesis showing operator precedence.

```
    EdgeVertex[Edge].x = in_Position.x + (VertexOffset[EdgeConnection[Edge][0]][0] + Offset * EdgeDirection[Edge][0]) * Scale;
    EdgeVertex[Edge].y = in_Position.y + (VertexOffset[EdgeConnection[Edge][0]][1] + Offset * EdgeDirection[Edge][1]) * Scale;
    EdgeVertex[Edge].z = in_Position.z + (VertexOffset[EdgeConnection[Edge][0]][2] + Offset * EdgeDirection[Edge][2]) * Scale;
```

Corrected, obtained Visine; resumed fun.